# Saving a file into Azure Blob storage

Tags: python, azure, save, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am running a Python code on Azure Machine Learning platform/cloud and I cannot figure out how to save a resulting dataframe into a csv file in the Azure Blob Storage. Can someone tell me how to do it or point me where I could read more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try uploading the file to Azure blog using below python code:

```
global service_client

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format("https", 'Storage_account_name'), credential='Storage_Account_Key')

#upload file to ADLS Gen 2
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="your_container_name")

directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")

file_client = directory_client.create_file("uploaded-file.txt")
local_file = open("C:\\Users\\xxxxxxx\\Desktop\\testFile.txt", 'r')

file_contents = local_file.read()

file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))

file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
```

**For more details to the complete code, visit** [this link](https://www.datastackpros.com/2020/05/upload-txt-file-to-azure-blob-storage.html)